# Methods for analysing android app on runtime

Tags: android, monitoring, debugging

I want to analyse security of android app by monitoring its behaviour on runtime. I need to monitor variables modifications, accesses and api calls while android app is running on the device. I tried to do this by JPDA framework and wrote my custom debugger. I succeeded in doing above task upto some extent but I am not moving any further due to some limitations in JPDA. Is there any method/tool available to do above tasks where I can also write my own logic to check security using above basic building blocks ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Frida](https://www.frida.re/docs/home/) it is an amazing dynamic instrumentation toolkit for developers, reverse-engineers, and security researchers. You can analyze the behavior of the application and run-time and you can easily perform run-time analysis using it.